# Ansible command with become and chdir

Tags: ansible, command

I have this:

```
- name: composer install in includes
      become: yes
      become_user: git
      become_method: sudo
      become_flags: '-s'
      chdir: /var/www/html/includes
      command: php /usr/local/bin/composer install
      creates: /var/www/html/includes/vendor
```

When I run it, I get an error 'Composer could not find a composer.json file in /home/git'.  But note that I specified a chdir to /var/www/html/includes which DOES have a composer.json. Note also that, while trying things out, I added become_method and become_flags.  -s should tell sudo not to change directories or load environments.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks, Ed

Answer (score 0):

I think the task should be written this way:

```
- name: composer install in includes
      become: yes
      become_user: git
      become_method: sudo
      become_flags: '-s'
      command: php /usr/local/bin/composer install
      args:
        chdir: /var/www/html/includes
        creates: /var/www/html/includes/vendor
```

For more information you can run:
`$ ansible-doc command`